# How to deploy on the JBoss via maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I'm trying to deploy on the JBoss AS 7 a web-application via `maven plugin`. I setted the configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <hostname>localhost</hostname>
        <jbossHome>D:\jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final</jbossHome>
        <fileName>target/corporate.war</fileName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But when I tried to execute mvn jboss-as:deploy I got the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.6.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project corporate: Error executing FORCE_DEPLOY: Operatio
n failed: Channel closed -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I would try the latest AS 7 release - 7.1.1.Final.